# I want the logo on my master slide to sit in front of objects on my slides

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm working in Powerpoint for Mac, version 16.51. I want to be able to place an element, my logo, on the master, and have it appear at the front of every slide. So if I place objects on top of the logo, you can still see it.

Answer (score 1):

Emily is correct. Harrymc's answer will give you an image on each slide, but it won't be atop the other shapes on the slide, so isn't really what you're after, if I understand correctly.

Here's a little macro that will do the job.
Before running it, select the shape (ie, your logo) that you want on each slide. Make sure it's in the same position as you want it to appear in throughout your presentation.

```
Sub LogoOnEachSlide()
    
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim oSl As Slide
    
    Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    
    oSh.Copy
    
    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        oSl.Shapes.Paste
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, it's unable to place a logo insetred in master slider on the top layer, as I think that the elements in the master slider and the non-master slider are in two containers, their layers can't be compared  with each other.

I suggest you search any add-ins online to add the logo and put it on the top layer.